# color a div inside a td using css

Tags: css

I have simple need to color a div inside a td element.
 If I use position:absolute the colored div fills up the entire screen, If I use relative nothing happens..

My code:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr height= "200px">
        <td>
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; background-color: green; position:relative; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; background-color: red; position:relative; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: what do you want exactly? and why should u use relative / absolute... Any reasons???

Comment: @KarthikN : I just wanted a div completely covering at td element

Comment: ok. Then go with cyborg86pl answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<td>` needs to be relative, `<div>` - absolute, then the td will be treated as a container to what's inside it.

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr height= "200px">
        <td style="position:relative;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; background-color: green; position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="position:relative;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; background-color: red; position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Also, it would be better to just create a stylesheet instead of style inside a tags

```
td{
    position:relative;
    ...
}
td div{
    position:absolute;
    ...
}
```